# Incorporating Crypto++ Library

Tags: c++, windows

I have a question about crypto++ Library.  I needed to implement aes encryption for my task at work. Decided to use this library. It is quite heavy when you build it. The lib turns out to be approximately 46MB. I was wondering if there is some easier way to implement the AES encryption without "reinventing the wheel". Or if you do use this library at work, how do you maintain it in any of the version control tools?

Comment: I never used Crypto++, but in general, you do not put the libraries you need in your version control tool, but just list them as dependencies. Then whoever wants to build your code provides the libraries and tells your build tool where to find them.

Comment: Be aware that [Crypto API is built into Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380255.aspx). You don't really need a third-party library.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I wanted to do it via Windows Api first but i could not find a good example where i could use an existing key that i have.. All of the example generate the key on the spot.